# iOS - Progressive Download Indicator While Downloading Files

Tags: ios, download, nsdata, progress

So this question has been asked a bunch of times, but all the answers are to us ASIHTTP library which is no longer supported.

So I was hoping someone could steer me in the right direction.
I download files (images / videos) in my app using NSData and was wondering how to go about displaying a progress bar/indicator that actually tracks the progress of the download (i.e. 20%, 30% etc etc)

Are there any built-in classes that allow file downloads to be tracked with progress updates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an `NSURLConnection` delegate then:

- the `NSURLResponse` you receive to `connection:didReceiveResponse:` will be of type `NSHTTPURLResponse`. If you access `[[response allHeaderFields] valueForKey:@"Content-Length"]` you'll get a string with the length of the data you're expecting to receive;
- subsequently through the accumulation of data via `connection:didReceiveData:` you'll know how much data has been returned.

Since you know how many bytes you've received and how many you're expecting you'll be able to work out the percentage pretty easily.

Comment: Hmm I didn't really think about trying to download files that way. I will give it a shot..

Comment: So how would I set the URL to download a file? I have only used NSURLConnections when grabbing JSON responses...

Comment: Oh, right, so you're just using `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:]`? You'd have to switch to creating a full on `NSURLConnection` and assigning a delegate. So you'd use `connectionWithRequest:delegate:` having created a suitable `NSURLRequest` with an `NSURL`.

Answer (score 1):

There are several replacement options for ASIHTTP.  The leading one is [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).  It includes support for a progress bar for downloads.

Comment: I am trying to stay away from too many 3rd party libraries and SDKs when possible. But I will look into this if I can't find a more native resolution.

Answer (score -1):

Check out ASIHTTPRequest . It is awesome an will do this any many more wonderous things.

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Comment: As the poster said, ASIHTTP is no longer under development and not a good long-term choice.

Comment: Ah sorry I missed that. I have been using it for years now and love it. And it is open source, so I change it if I need it.